# How to prevent WSDL refresh in testsuite?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

In SoapUI 5.3.0 I created a testcase for a SOAP webservice. There are 3 SOAP requests in the testcase.

I noticed that when executing the testcase, the WSDL is reloaded before the first and third SOAP request, but not for the second one (or maybe even then, but is too quick to notice. Is there some log for this?).

Why does SoapUI reload the WSDL in those cases? Is it some setting? I checked the settings and could not find anything related. My settings are mostly default.

I do not want the WSDL to be reloaded each time, as I consider it to be part of the test and should stay the same, unless I change it willingly.

Here is an image of what happens, taken right after starting the testcase:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the "Cache Definitions" setting, documented here: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html ?

Comment: @SiKing I have that setting at TRUE (which is the default).

Comment: I always put the wsdl, asmx type codes into another class library file to avoid recompiling situations that you describe. I would check the soapui documentation as @SiKing has described.

Comment: @Programmer The page SiKing linked does not mention class or libraries. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @DavidBalažic I don't think my answer fits your scenario. Is this test class nUnit part of a solution using visual studio?

Comment: @Programmer No, there is no Visual Studio involved.